# retrieving shared preferences value from asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to get values from shared preferences and it is returning null. The shared preference value is set from an asynctask. I tested it from inside the asynctask, printing the stord value in a toast and it worked, but problem is when I try the retrive the value outside the asynctask by clicking on the buttonRegister, it display null. There is no error shown into the logcat.

The code of the Activity:

```html
package com.example.mohalogin;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Properties;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
 
 private EditText editTextName;
    private EditText editTextUsername;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private EditText editTextEmail;

    private Button buttonRegister;
    private Button buttonLogin;
    //private Button gmail,yahoo;
    Context context;
    
    private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
 public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPreferences" ;
 public static final String RegisResult = "result";
    
    
    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "xxxxxxxxxx"; //fake data

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
  
  editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);
      
       
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
             registerUser();
             
             sharedpreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
             
             buttonLogin.setText(sharedpreferences.getString("result","")); //testing by printing the value in the button
             
            }
        });
        

        /*buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){
             
             startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                
            }
        });*/
 }
 
        private void registerUser() {
  
  String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();

        register(name,username,password,email); 
 }
 
 private void register(String name, String username, String password, String email) {
        class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
         
         ProgressDialog loading;
            RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();
            private Context context2;
            
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterActivity.this, "Please Wait","Registering new user", true, false);
            }

   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    
    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
                data.put("name",params[0]);
                data.put("username",params[1]);
                data.put("password",params[2]);
                data.put("email",params[3]);

                String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(REGISTER_URL,data);
    
                return  result;
    
   }
   
   @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                
                sharedpreferences = context2.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, context2.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(RegisResult, s);
    editor.commit();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sharedpreferences.getString("result",""), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                
            } 
   
   public RegisterUser(Context context2)
   {
    this.context2=context2;
   }
        }

        RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser(getApplicationContext());
        ru.execute(name, username, password, email);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the call to getSharedPreferences(String, int) -

You basically use two separate SharePreference instances, since you are passing a different name (String) for the SharedPreferences each time -

When you store the value, you are using 
`getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", context2.MODE_PRIVATE);`

And when you try to obtain the value, you are using 
`getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);`

Modify your code to use the same SharedPreference name and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign part of the code to be executed by the AsyncTask, it is actually executed in a new thread, other than the Ui thread. Actually in the **onClick** of the **ButtonRegister**, the **registerUser()** and **the following two lines**, run in **parallel mode not sequentially**. 
If you want to make sure that saving in SharedPreferences is completed successfully, you can read it again and set the button text. Alter the **OnPostExecute** of your AsyncTask this way:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) 
{
     super.onPostExecute(s);
     loading.dismiss();
     .
     .
     .


    buttonLogin.setText(sharedpreferences.getString("result",""));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the value at the wrong place.
Try this code instead :)

```
package com.example.mohalogin;

    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

        private EditText editTextName;
        private EditText editTextUsername;
        private EditText editTextPassword;
        private EditText editTextEmail;

        private Button buttonRegister;
        private Button buttonLogin;
        //private Button gmail,yahoo;
        Context context;

        private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
        public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPreferences" ;
        public static final String RegisResult = "result";


        private static final String REGISTER_URL = "xxxxxxxxxx"; //fake data

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
            sharedpreferences=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
            editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
            editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
            editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
            editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);

            buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
            buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);


            buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0){
                    registerUser();





                }
            });


            /*buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0){

                    startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

                }
            });*/
        }

            private void registerUser() {

            String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
            String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
            String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
            String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();

            register(name,username,password,email); 
        }

        private void register(String name, String username, String password, String email) {
            class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                ProgressDialog loading;
                RegisterUserClass ruc = new RegisterUserClass();
                private Context context2;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    loading = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterActivity.this, "Please Wait","Registering new user", true, false);
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    data.put("name",params[0]);
                    data.put("username",params[1]);
                    data.put("password",params[2]);
                    data.put("email",params[3]);

                    String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(REGISTER_URL,data);

                    return  result;

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute();
                    loading.dismiss();

                    sharedpreferences = context2.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, context2.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString(RegisResult, s);
                    editor.commit();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),sharedpreferences.getString("result",""), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    buttonLogin.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(RegisResult,"")); //testing by printing the value in the button
                }   

                public RegisterUser(Context context2)
                {
                    this.context2=context2;
                }
            }

            RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser(getApplicationContext());
            ru.execute(name, username, password, email);

    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to retrieve the value outside the `asynctask`, it display null because the asynctask didn't finish. Whatever you need to do with the data you get it in the executing of the `asyncTask`, you need to do it inside of `onPostExecute`, it is the only place where you can be sure the `asyncTask` already finish.

Answer (score 0):

Re-instantiate your Shared-preference after the commit.